# How to use original names when using find -exec?

Tags: ffmpeg, find

There are `.mp4` files I want to convert.

```
$ find . -name '*.mp4'
./01.mp4
./02.mp4
./03.mp4
```

I expected to output files `copy-01.mp4`, `copy-02.mp4` and `copy-03.mp4` with this command.

```
find . -name '*.mp4' -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c copy -aspect 16:9 copy-{} ";"
```

But it failed with errors `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'copy-'`.
I thought `{}` represents the file name, isn't it?

How can I use original file names when using `-exec` option of `find`?

The `find` version is:

```
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version e5573b1bad88bfabcda181b9e0125fb0c52b7d3b
Features enabled: O_NOFOLLOW(disabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS() CBO(level=0)
```

This is `xargs` version.

```
xargs --version
xargs (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version e5573b1bad88bfabcda181b9e0125fb0c52b7d3b
```

### Result of ffmpeg

```
$ find * -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c copy -aspect 16:9 copy-{} ";"

# almost same outputs several times here.

ffmpeg version N-50911-g9efcfbe Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 13 2013 21:26:48 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 19.100 / 52. 19.100
  libavcodec     55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavformat    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavdevice    54.  4.100 / 54.  4.100
  libavfilter     3. 45.103 /  3. 45.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '24.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2012-11-01 13:42:12
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.8 2012071700
  Duration: 00:24:58.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 474 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x256, 341 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-11-01 13:42:12
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-11-01 13:42:12
```

Comment: Wondering why do you have such an error - maybe {} is empty? Could you try  

    find . -name '*.mp4' -exec echo MyFile: {} ";"

Comment: Why use such an old `ffmpeg` build? See [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to recent builds.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way would be to make a bash script. The problem is the current directory prefix `./`

If you really must you can do:

```
find * -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c copy -aspect 16:9 copy-{} ";"
```

Or if you have `xargs`:

```
find . -name '*.mp4' | xargs -L1 basename | xargs -L1 -I{} ffmpeg -i {} -c copy -aspect 16:9 copy-{}
```

Comment: Thanks, but first one ends up same ` Unable to find a suitable output format for 'copy-'` and second one returns `xargs: {}: No such file or directory`. I'm using Railsinstaller/Devkit commands, more details about the command I'll add in my question.

Comment: That's weird, I have the same versions and both commands work. Can you post the full ffmpeg console output in your question?

Answer (score 1):

To have files accessed by ffmpeg if  even they are several directory levels behind the current dir, you need to pass the whole source path as -i argument but basename only as the destination file name building block.

If you want them to copy into the current dir (flattened),

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c copy -aspect 16:9 copy-"`basename {}`" ";"
```

If they should be placed in the same directories as sources:

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c copy -aspect 16:9 "`dirname {}`"/copy-"`basename {}`" ";"
```

Comment: Thanks, but somehow `basename` doesn't work properly in my environments. ` find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec echo `basename {}` ";"` returns `./01.mp4`, `./02.mp4`. But `basename './01.mp4'` returns `01.mp4`.

Comment: Did you quoted basename twice:  .... echo "\`basename\`"    (note back-single-quotes) ?

Comment: ah, I only quoted `basename` once. first quote is for markdown in stackoverflow. I don't know how to avoid the markdown...

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a job for a one-liner. Try a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' FILE
do
    BASE=$(basename "$FILE")
    COPYFILE=${FILE/$BASE/copy-$BASE}
    ffmpeg -i "$FILE" -c copy -aspect 16:9 "$COPYFILE"
done < <(find . -name '*.mp4' -print0)
```

(Of course, with a few semicolons you could also put this on one line if you really wanted!)

Comment: Somehow your script doesn't work in my environment, but it's good to know there is no easy way to do it in a one-liner. I wrote a ruby script for it. `Dir.glob("*.mp4").each{|file| system("ffmpeg -i #{file} -c copy -aspect 16:9 copy_#{file}") }`

Answer (score 0):

To use a shell parameter expansion, this style would be better.

```
find * -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i $0 -c copy -aspect 16:9 copy-$0' {} \;
```